# Parsing a datetime string to local time in rust chrono

Tags: datetime, parsing, rust

Having trouble with a simple problem. I have a string that does not include timezone information that I need to parse into a DateTime struct. I can get it as UTC, but not local:

```
let from = NaiveDateTime::parse_from_str(&start_date, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")?;
let from_utc = DateTime::<Utc>::from_utc(from, Utc);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [`Local.from_local_datetime()`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.19/chrono/offset/trait.TimeZone.html?search=#tymethod.offset_from_local_datetime) to convert a `NaiveDateTime` into a `DateTime<Local>`:

```
let from: NaiveDateTime = start_date.parse().unwrap();
let date_time = Local.from_local_datetime(&from).unwrap();
```

Admittedly, this isn't really easy to find in the documentation.

The first line you have works fine as well. For this particular format (RFC3339), it's easier to use `str::parse()`, though.